# Colors of GLTF models are too pale with react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm doing a project with [react-three-fiber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-three/fiber) and included my Blender model (a .glb file) with `useGLTF` (from the [drei](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-three/drei) package). It seems to work but the colors are off, all the parts are way too pale.

The stretched cube (a `boxGeometry` from R3F) and the cylinder (glb model) have the same material and the same color assigned, but the pink of the cube is much stronger.

I did some googling and think that it might be the encoding, but I do not know to what I have to assign it.

e.g. https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader

```
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

but I don't have a renderer object with R3F, nor has the material a texture

[image]

### Update

When I apply `<Canvas linear>` both objects have the same color, but both not the vibrant version

[image]